# Using yield from an event handler

Tags: c#, events, yield

I have a method `Foo.LongRunningMethod()`, which does some very complicated processing that may go on for a long time. Along the way, it fires `Foo.InterestingEvent` whenever it encounters a certain condition. I'd like to be able to expose an enumeration of those events, and I'd like to be able to start iterating before `LongRunningMethod` actually finishes. In other words, what I want is something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<InterestingObject> GetInterestingObjects()
{
    foo.InterestingEvent += (obj) => { yield return obj; }
    foo.LongRunningMethod();

    yield break;
}
```

This doesn't work, though, for the sensible reason that you can't `yield return` from an anonymous method (and because a method using `yield` cannot return `void`, which our event handler does). Is there another idiom that allows me to accomplish this? Or is this just a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This quote from Tim Robinson's answer got me thinking:

> What you're doing is turning a push sequence (occurrences of an event) into a pull one (calls into IEnumerable).

Turning a push sequence into a pull sequence is difficult, and the root of my problems here. But the reverse (turning a pull sequence into a push sequence) is trivial, and this insight gave me the solution. I changed `LongRunningMethod` into an internal enumerable version, with the trivial refactoring of replacing every event callback with `yield return` and adding a `yield break` at the end. Then I turned the existing `LongRunningMethod` into a wrapper that just fires the event for everything returned:

```
internal IEnumerable<InterestingObject> FindInterestingObjects() 
{ 
    /* etc */ 
}

public void LongRunningMethod()
{
    foreach (var obj in FindInterestingObjects())
    {
        OnInterestingEvent(obj);
    }
}
```

This preserves the public interface, while giving me a neat enumeration that I can use for the scenarios that require it. As a significant side-benefit, this also allows me to abandon the long computation early if I want to, something that would be difficult to do with event-based or multi-threaded versions.

Comment: When and where did he say this? And what can I read to learn more about the push and pull?

Answer (score 5):

You want to be able to subscribe to a stream of events that come from `LongRunningMethod` and, when an event occurs, yield another value from an `IEnumerable`? You might find the .NET Reactive Extensions useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx

The reactive extensions give you `IObservable`, which is in effect a push-only `IEnumerable`. You can create an `IObservable` wrapper around an event (such as your `InterestingEvent`) and do enumerable-style processing on it from there (such as yielding a stream of objects).

> **Edit:** "is there an idiom that allows me to accomplish this" other than adopting a new library from Microsoft? What you're doing is turning a push sequence (occurrences of an event) into a pull one (calls into `IEnumerable`).
>
> The pulls and pushes probably aren't going to be coordinated, so you'll need somewhere to buffer new values that were pushed before a pull was made. The most straightforward way might be to adopt a producer-consumer arrangement: push those into a `List<T>` that's consumed by the caller of `GetInterestingObjects`.
>
> Depending on how the events are raised, you might need to put the producer and consumer on separate threads. (All of this is what the reactive extensions end up doing, when you ask it to convert between an `IObservable` and an `IEnumerable`.)

Answer (score 2):

I would run `LongRunningMethod()` in a separate thread communicating with the main thread: The event handler pushes the `InterestingObject`s into some synchronized queue and signals the main thread, when a new value arrives.

The main thread waits for objects in the queue and returns them using `yield` to return them.

Alternatively you could also block the subthread every time an event is raised until the main thread has returned the value and the consumer of the`IEnumerable` requests the next value.